# Jquery to change src of a script tag using a select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **I need to change the value of the src in the tag**     :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='gray.js'></script>
```

For this I'm using a combobox:

```
<select id="chartTheme">
   <option value="dark-blue">Dark Blue</option>
   <option value="gray">Gray</option>
</select>
```

How to make it use a Jquery function when I select and click in a refresh button?

Source to refresh button:

```
<input type="image" name="commit" src="../icons/refresh.png" onClick="javascript:updateGraph()"></input>
```

Comment: Why do you want to change src? Just load a new script by getScript?

Comment: why do you want to load two different script files? It would be better to use a single file for you code and make your calls read a variable which you manipulate when you change the selection ...

Comment: The original script will already be loaded. No point in changing `.src.`  may as well just load a new script or call a different function in the same script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$.getScript()` for this purpose. It loads a new script into the page and runs the code inside.

```
function updateGraph()
{
    var sel = $('#chartTheme').val();

    $.getScript(sel + '.js');
}
```

Comment: But, i have another scripts, like

`<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/charts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @HelioBentzen I don't see how that affects anything?

Comment: Forget it. it's working.. i just need use a timeout to load my graph because I called other function to render. Thanks a lot, Jack!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#chartTheme').change(function () {
    var optionVal = $(this).val();
    console.log(optionVal);
    updateGraph();
});
```

Comment: -1. "I need to change the value of the src in the tag" - I don't see how that's addressed here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be like this:

```
$('input[name="commit"]').click(function(){
    var srcExt = $('#chartTheme').val();
    $('<script'+' type="text/javascript"'+' src='+ srcExt +'></'+'script>').appendTo('body');
});
```

Comment: When I try it, the java make a wrong intrepretation of the <script'

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#chartTheme').change(function () {
    var optionVal = $(this).val();
    var miSrc = "someSrc";
    $('input.someClass').attr('src', miSrc);
    updateGraph();
});
```