# Can <script>...</script> tags be editted by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, implementation, theory

Ok, so this is entirely theoretical (If this WERE possible, I can see it leading to nightmarish implementation), but script tags read similar to other HTML tags. Short of causing a blackhole and destroying my computer and love ones, what would happen if I were to try and give a script tag an ID and remove it using?

```
$('#scriptobject').remove();
```

Comment: Why dont you try it, and report back? lol

Comment: just removing script tag will not remove the script which is already evaluated.

Comment: +1 for `Short of causing a blackhole and destroying my computer and love ones`

Comment: It will get removed from the dom.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486144/should-a-script-tag-be-allowed-to-remove-itself

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?  The script tags can be removed from the DOM but doing so won't unload any JavaScript.

Comment: sure. why wouldn't this possible? `script` tags are tags just like any other tags.

Comment: Huh. Reading the previous comment, would this be a way to somewhat abstract and hide your code from someone wanting understand your page (for legitimate or illegitimate reasons)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*what would happen if I were to try and give a script tag an ID and remove it*

Yes, you can add id attribute to your script tag -

```
<script id='jq' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

when you try to remove script tag using id `#jq`, that script tag will be removed from DOM

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/medTp/1/

```
$(function(){
   $('#jq').remove();
   console.log($('html').html());
   $('body').append('works');
});
```

You can see on console, that script tag is removed,

And the next two statement's make use of `$` , so you can be sure that even if the tag is removed, the script is still there in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can give an ID to a script tag:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html

But as pXL said, you can remove the script, and load a new one:

[Jquery to change src of a script tag using a select value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532551/jquery-to-change-src-of-a-script-tag-using-a-select-value)